# QuickOpen file in VSCode extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to be able to quickselect a file in an extension, but if I use `executeCommand` to run the `workbench.action.quickOpen` command I can't recover the selected file and it just opens in a new editor.

Is there an officially supported way to do this? Or do I have to build an array of all files in the workspace and create a `QuickPick` with them?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but `workbench.action.files.openFile` is another option.  It also opens in a new editor tab, are you trying to avoid that?  From there you can get the currentEditor via ` vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.fileName` for example.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to avoid that, I would like the UI (ie quick pick with all workspace files inserted), but I'd like it to just return the selected file and do nothing to it.

Comment: Then I think you'll have to go the `QuickPick` route.

Comment: Is there no way to have a prepopulated `QuickPick` file icons and all?